# How can I reference an assembly in T4 in a way that's supported by both Visual Studio 2010 and TextTransform.exe?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, t4

VS2010 introduces a new way to reference assemblies in T4: http://weblogs.asp.net/lhunt/archive/2010/05/04/t4-template-error-assembly-directive-cannot-locate-referenced-assembly-in-visual-studio-2010-project.aspx

These new ways sure seem great, and I've upgraded my t4 files to work this way, but I'd like something that's executable from both visual studio and the command line. I'm currently using TextTransform.exe, and it doesn't seem to matter which version I use, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\10.0` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\1.2`, it requires the old, VS2008 style assembly references (i'm using the -P, reference path, parameter).

Is there a way I can reference custom assemblies from a t4 file that works in both visual studio 2010 and from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using TextTransform.exe only for testing?  If so, you might want to consider using VS macros for the paths and replacing them in the template files in your test setup phase.

Comment: No i'm using the exe file for manual, batched builds. I actually run the template once for each language that my app supports.

Comment: Would adding a step at the beginning of the batch process to replace any VS macros in the assembly directives be an option?

Comment: to actually edit the t4 file itself? That just might work as a last resort :)

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's awful.  Unfortunately, every alternative of which I'm aware is worse...

Comment: I ended up manually replacing the macro in the t4 files with a powershell script. Not elegant, but it works

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we didn't have time to make equivalent updates to TextTransform.exe so that it matches the built-in Visual Studio 2010 experience in this release cycle. The workarounds suggested above are your best bet at present.

We're thinking about ways to get something out there currently, but I don't have an ETA for you I'm afraid.

I'm interested to get feedback on texttransform.exe/T4msbuild prioritization - which matters most to the community?

Comment: Hi Gareth, thanks for the official comment. Personally I'm using texttransform.exe, and am quite ignorant of t4msbuild. If the exe was upgraded, surely msbuild could just shell out?

Comment: Yeah, you can shell out from msbuild, but it doesn't give a very nice or performant experience.  Our msbuild support is currently done with an in-process ITask for msbuild.